# sql запрос выборка по нескольким условиям

Tags: sql-server

Есть запрос, который возвращает два поля

```
SELECT 
firma.fname AS "Название", COUNT(zakaz.codf) AS "Количество заказов"
    FROM firma 
    JOIN Zakaz ON firma.codf = zakaz.codf WHERE firma.fname = 'BBB'

     GROUP BY firma.fname;
```

Как можно добавить третье поле, которое тоже будет возвращать количество записей по условию. Чтоб вышла таблица из трех полей. Не получается скомбинировать

```
JOIN Zakaz ON firma.codf = zakaz.codf WHERE firma.fname = 'BBB' AND zakaz.nomer = 2
```

Comment: Странный запрос... И группировка, и отбор - по одному полю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT firma.fname AS "Название"
     , COUNT(zakaz.codf) AS "Количество заказов"
     , SUM(CASE WHEN zakaz.nomer = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "что-то там"
FROM firma 
JOIN Zakaz ON firma.codf = zakaz.codf 
WHERE firma.fname = 'BBB'
GROUP BY firma.fname;
```